# Base64 encoding a serialized svg element ouputs unicode instead of UTF8

Tags: javascript, svg, unicode, highcharts

I am trying to create a html file which has a chart from highcharts embedded as an image. The reason for this is I have a web application and I want to create a html report with some info that can be sent to people in an email.

```
 var s = new XMLSerializer();
 $(document).find('.highcharts-container').find('svg').attr('id','svg');
 objs.meta_data.config.bar_timeline = btoa(s.serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg')));
```

The code above will create the `objs.meta_data.bar_timeline` string which is then fed into a Mustache rendering function. The template for this looks like:

```
<h2>Timeline:</h2>
      <br><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{config.bar_timeline}}"  alt="Timeline chart - if you can't see me then open in Chrome"/><br>
```

When I get this output and open it in IE 11 it does not render, I get the alt text. However, opening in Chrome does render the image.

When I open the file in Atom I see that there is two unicode encoded '&#x3D&#x3D' at the end of the string. When I change these to '==' the image renders OK.

```
<h2>Timeline:</h2>
      <br><img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,base64,PHN2ZyB4bWx...c3ZnPg&#x3D;&#x3D;"    alt="Timeline chart - if you can't see me then open in Chrome"/><br>
```

Is there some argument to the serializer that I need to provide to escape the equals at the end in utf8 instead of unicode?

EDIT: 
The `serialiseToString` method is outputting the following in IE11

`<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" class=\"highcharts-root\" id=\"svg\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;\" width=\"1650\" height=\"500\" version=\"1.1\"><desc>Created with Highcharts 5.0.6</desc><defs><linearGradient id=\"highcharts-o82icmm-79\" x1=\"0\" y1=\"0\" x2=\"1\" y2=\"1\"><stop stop-color=\"#272b30\" stop-opacity=\"1\" offset=\"0\" /><stop stop-color=\"#272b30\" stop-opacity=\"1\" offset=\"1\" /></linearGradient><clipPath id=\"highcharts-o82icmm-80\"><rect fill=\"none\" x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1570\" height=\"353\" /></clipPath></defs><rect class=\"highcharts-background\" fill=\"url(#highcharts-o82icmm-79)\" x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1650\" height=\"500\" rx=\"0\" ry=\"0\" /><rect class=\"highcharts-plot-background\" fill=\"none\" x=\"70\" y=\"70\" width=\"1570\" height=\"353\" /><g class=\"highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid \"><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 462.5 70 L 462.5 423\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 854.5 70 L 854.5 423\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 1247.5 70 L 1247.5 423\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 1639.5 70 L 1639.5 423\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 69.5 70 L 69.5 423\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid \"><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 423.5 L 1640 423.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 364.5 L 1640 364.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 305.5 L 1640 305.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 247.5 L 1640 247.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 188.5 L 1640 188.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 129.5 L 1640 129.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-grid-line\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 69.5 L 1640 69.5\" /></g><rect class=\"highcharts-plot-border\" fill=\"none\" x=\"70\" y=\"70\" width=\"1570\" height=\"353\" /><g class=\"highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis \"><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 462.5 423 L 462.5 433\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 854.5 423 L 854.5 433\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 1247.5 423 L 1247.5 433\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 1640.5 423 L 1640.5 433\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 69.5 423 L 69.5 433\" /><path class=\"highcharts-axis-line\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 423.5 L 1640 423.5\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis \"><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 423.5 L 60 423.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 364.5 L 60 364.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 305.5 L 60 305.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 247.5 L 60 247.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 188.5 L 60 188.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 129.5 L 60 129.5\" /><path class=\"highcharts-tick\" opacity=\"1\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#707073\" stroke-width=\"1\" d=\"M 70 69.5 L 60 69.5\" /><text class=\"highcharts-axis-title\" style=\"color: rgb(160, 160, 163); fill: #a0a0a3;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0) rotate(270 26.13 246.5)\" x=\"26.13\" y=\"246.5\">Hours</text><path class=\"highcharts-axis-line\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M 70 70 L 70 423\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-series-group\"><g class=\"highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker\" clip-path=\"url(&quot;#highcharts-o82icmm-80&quot;)\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\"><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-0\" fill=\"#49b6de\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"101.5\" y=\"104.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"49\" /><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-0\" fill=\"#49b6de\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"494.5\" y=\"55.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"59\" /><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-0\" fill=\"#49b6de\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"886.5\" y=\"353.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"0\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-0 \" clip-path=\"none\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\" /><g class=\"highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker\" clip-path=\"url(&quot;#highcharts-o82icmm-80&quot;)\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\"><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-1\" fill=\"#4fc462\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"101.5\" y=\"153.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"200\" /><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-1\" fill=\"#4fc462\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"494.5\" y=\"114.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"239\" /><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-1\" fill=\"#4fc462\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"886.5\" y=\"353.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"0\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-1 \" clip-path=\"none\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\" /><g class=\"highcharts-series highcharts-series-2 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-2 highcharts-tracker\" clip-path=\"url(&quot;#highcharts-o82icmm-80&quot;)\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\"><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-2\" fill=\"#ee5341\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"1279.5\" y=\"353.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"0\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-markers highcharts-series-2 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-2 \" clip-path=\"none\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\" /><g class=\"highcharts-series highcharts-series-3 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-3 highcharts-tracker\" clip-path=\"url(&quot;#highcharts-o82icmm-80&quot;)\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\"><rect class=\"highcharts-point highcharts-color-3\" fill=\"#7a8288\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"886.5\" y=\"353.5\" width=\"189\" height=\"0\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-markers highcharts-series-3 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-3 \" clip-path=\"none\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\" width=\"353\" height=\"1570\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" transform=\"translate(1616 10)\"><title>Chart context menu</title><rect class=\" highcharts-button-box\" fill=\"#505053\" stroke=\"none\" stroke-width=\"1\" x=\"0.5\" y=\"0.5\" width=\"24\" height=\"22\" rx=\"2\" ry=\"2\" /><path class=\"highcharts-button-symbol\" fill=\"#666666\" stroke=\"#dddddd\" stroke-width=\"3\" d=\"M 6 6.5 L 20 6.5 M 6 11.5 L 20 11.5 M 6 16.5 L 20 16.5\" /><text style=\"color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: normal; fill: #333333;\" x=\"0\" y=\"12\"></text></g><text class=\"highcharts-title\" style=\"width: 1586px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"825\" y=\"25\"><tspan>GENERIC_Dual_WT_Ck1T2_XYZ_NOSO_2017_01_23_14_28_45_execute_126.6hrs</tspan></text><text class=\"highcharts-subtitle\" style=\"width: 1586px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); text-transform: uppercase; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"825\" y=\"52\"><tspan>Official ASML and Local WOW Timings</tspan></text><g class=\"highcharts-stack-labels\" visibility=\"visible\" transform=\"translate(70 70)\"><text style=\"color: white; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: white; text-shadow: none; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"196\" y=\"98\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#000000\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"196\" y=\"98\">105.6</tspan><tspan x=\"196\" y=\"98\">105.6</tspan></text><text style=\"color: white; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: white; text-shadow: none; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"589\" y=\"49\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#000000\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"589\" y=\"49\">126.6</tspan><tspan x=\"589\" y=\"49\">126.6</tspan></text><text style=\"color: white; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: white; text-shadow: none; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"981\" y=\"347\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#000000\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"981\" y=\"347\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"981\" y=\"347\">0</tspan></text><text style=\"color: white; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: white; text-shadow: none; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"1374\" y=\"347\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#000000\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"1374\" y=\"347\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"1374\" y=\"347\">0</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker\" opacity=\"1\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\"><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(180 117)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">20.8</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">20.8</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(573 73)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">24.9</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">24.9</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(973 333)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan></text></g></g><g class=\"highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-1 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker\" opacity=\"1\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\"><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(180 241)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">84.8</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">84.8</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(570 221)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">101.7</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">101.7</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-1 \" visibility=\"hidden\" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" opacity=\"0\" transform=\"translate(973 333)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan></text></g></g><g class=\"highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-2 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-2 highcharts-tracker\" opacity=\"1\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\"><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-2 \" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" transform=\"translate(1366 333)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan></text></g></g><g class=\"highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-3 highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-3 highcharts-tracker\" opacity=\"1\" transform=\"translate(70 70) scale(1)\"><g class=\"highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-3 \" visibility=\"hidden\" style=\"text-shadow: none;\" opacity=\"0\" transform=\"translate(973 333)\"><text style=\"color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; fill: black; text-outline: 1px contrast;\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\"><tspan class=\"highcharts-text-outline\" fill=\"#ffffff\" stroke=\"#ffffff\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-width=\"2px\" x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan><tspan x=\"5\" y=\"16\">0</tspan></text></g></g><g class=\"highcharts-legend\" transform=\"translate(614 458)\"><rect class=\"highcharts-legend-box\" visibility=\"visible\" fill=\"none\" x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"422\" height=\"27\" rx=\"0\" ry=\"0\" /><g><g><g class=\"highcharts-legend-item highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-series-0\" transform=\"translate(8 3)\"><text style=\"color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"start\" x=\"21\" y=\"15\"><tspan>Customer request time</tspan></text><rect class=\"highcharts-point\" fill=\"#49b6de\" x=\"2\" y=\"4\" width=\"12\" height=\"12\" rx=\"6\" ry=\"6\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-legend-item highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-series-1\" transform=\"translate(192.68 3)\"><text style=\"color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"start\" x=\"21\" y=\"15\"><tspan>ARE Time</tspan></text><rect class=\"highcharts-point\" fill=\"#4fc462\" x=\"2\" y=\"4\" width=\"12\" height=\"12\" rx=\"6\" ry=\"6\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-legend-item highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-2 highcharts-series-2\" transform=\"translate(290.63 3)\"><text style=\"color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"start\" x=\"21\" y=\"15\">Delay</text><rect class=\"highcharts-point\" fill=\"#ee5341\" x=\"2\" y=\"4\" width=\"12\" height=\"12\" rx=\"6\" ry=\"6\" /></g><g class=\"highcharts-legend-item highcharts-column-series highcharts-color-3 highcharts-series-3\" transform=\"translate(366.54 3)\"><text style=\"color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; fill: #e0e0e3;\" text-anchor=\"start\" x=\"21\" y=\"15\">Lost</text><rect class=\"highcharts-point\" fill=\"#7a8288\" x=\"2\" y=\"4\" width=\"12\" height=\"12\" rx=\"6\" ry=\"6\" /></g></g></g></g><g class=\"highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels \"><text style=\"width: 398px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"266.25\" y=\"442\"><tspan>A-Time</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 398px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"658.75\" y=\"442\"><tspan>B-Time</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 398px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"1051.25\" y=\"442\"><tspan>Actual</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 398px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"middle\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"1443.75\" y=\"442\"><tspan>Delays</tspan></text></g><g class=\"highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels \"><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"427\"><tspan>0</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"368\"><tspan>25</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"309\"><tspan>50</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"250\"><tspan>75</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"191\"><tspan>100</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"132\"><tspan>125</tspan></text><text style=\"width: 535px; color: rgb(224, 224, 227); font-size: 11px; cursor: default; -ms-text-overflow: clip; fill: #e0e0e3;\" opacity=\"1\" text-anchor=\"end\" transform=\"translate(0)\" x=\"55\" y=\"74\"><tspan>150</tspan></text></g><text class=\"highcharts-credits\" style=\"color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 9px; cursor: pointer; fill: #666;\" text-anchor=\"end\" x=\"1640\" y=\"495\">Highcharts.com</text></svg>`

When I escape the html in Mustache like:

```
<h2>Timeline:</h2>
          <br><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,{{{config.bar_timeline}}}"    alt="Timeline chart - if you can't see me then open in Chrome"/><br>
```

The output is like :

```
<h2>Timeline:</h2>
  <br><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Z...y3ZnPg==" alt="Timeline chart - if you can't see me then open in Chrome"/><br>
```

Still does not render

Comment: Have you determined via a debugger whether these are originating from btoa or serialiseToString? Do both IE11 and Chrome create the unicode encoded terminal characters?

Comment: It has nothing to do with unicode, the `=` sign is html encoded. Check moustache for encoding options

Comment: _"ouputs unicode instead of UTF8"_ - Not an answer to your question, but please put some time aside to read [this excellent article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks like it might be a valuable read